# HTML Auto Concatinate to String

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a function or a plugin in PhpStorm which converts

```
<center id="no_records_text">
      <h1>
         NO RECORDS.
      </h1>
</center>
```

to

```
'<center id="no_records_text">'+
      '<h1>'+
         'NO RECORDS.'+
      '</h1>'+
'</center>
```

automatically? Because I can't find any function or plugin.

Comment: maybe webstorm has this? As a poor mans alternative you can use find/replace......

Answer (score 0):

Select the block of text you want to convert then Search:

```
^(\s*)(.*)\s*$
```

with "Regex" and "In Selection" checked, and Replace All with:

```
$1'$2'+
```

You will get an extra `+` at the end of the last line but it is easy to remove it by hand after you deselect the text.

Not quite an automated way to do it, I afraid. I tried to record a macro while doing these operations but, for some reason, it doesn't have the same effect when the macro is played :-(